# How to compare JARs in Araxis Merge?

Tags: jar, compare, archive, araxis

I'm using Araxis Merge to try and compare two Java archive files. I've done it in Beyond Compare but have recently switched to a Mac. Right now Araxis treats the JARs like files and I just see a lot of binary/hex stuff. I'd like to see which classes have differences and to treat the JAR like a folder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Decompress the contents of the archive to folders, and diff the folders

Comment: And before starting the diff, you could decompile the .class files. Might not be very useful if they were obfuscated or a major change happened.

Answer (score 0):

A JAR file is basically a zip file with a different extension.
Araxis merge can't compare the content inside a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

A JAR file is basically a ZIP file with a different extension. Araxis Merge can't compare the content inside a ZIP file.

As a workaround, decompress the contents of the archive to folders. Then diff the folders.